# Using WPF's Point and Color class on Mono

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mono

I am developing an application that has a client and server. Each share similar code through a shared class library. The class library and server both rely on WPF's [`Color`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (in PresentationCore.dll) and [`Point`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.point%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (in WindowsBase.dll) classes. (But *only* rely on these two WPF classes)

The server and client library run on Linux using Mono just fine, until code is executed that uses the `Color` or `Point` class, as WPF is not ported to Mono.

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.

I fixed the issue by adding my own `PresentationCore.dll` from my local machine (In hopes of mono "transposing" the code as it does with application), which fixes the issue, until the color class is needed. (However, the point class now works fine)

Using the the color class results in:

> System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in System.Windows.Media.Color:Fr                  omRgb (byte,byte,byte): method body is empty.

I have tried using `extern alias` and implementing the Mono Moon version of the color class, found [here](https://github.com/mono/moon/blob/master/class/System.Windows/System.Windows.Media/Color.cs). Using a this on the server, and the version from PresentationCore on the client, along with different alias for each, works, somewhat. It works fine on the server end, but WPF cannot cast the Mono version of the class to the WPF version, when the client needs to use an object that contains `Color`. (I could cast automatically, but then I would be in the opposite situation, of the client working but not the server)

Anyways, that is the research I have found so far. One thought I had was trying to compile [Mono Moon](https://github.com/mono/moon/blob/master/class/System.Windows/System.Windows.Media/Color.cs) and adding it to the Mono GAC or my program directory, although I cannot figure out how to compile it (Specifically, making "configure"), and whether it would even work.

**Is there a way to use the WPF `Color` class on Mono in my situation? (The rest of the WPF framework is not needed)** Remember that the shared library that contains objects using the Color class, is shared between the client and the server.

Comment: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Media/Color.cs,81b49d14d2231b78 might help you

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just include your own `Color` and `Point` classes? Depending on WPF in a server app doesn't sound right to me, even more so when it's just for two simple types.

Comment: @AlexanderKöplinger The server and client both use a shared library that has common objects such as a user, different entities, and messages. I actually solved this by using `#if MONO Color = MyCustomColorClass;` but maybe there are some better ways.